# Eclipse ADT virtual machine won't start

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt, eclipse-adt

Please note this is not a duplicate. I have found no thread that solves my issue.

I opened up fresh install of eclipse adt with hello world example and opened Android Virtual Device Manager. Here, I added several devices with different configuration and hit start on each of them but all I got is starting virtual device then .. nothing happens. No log, no alert, nothing.

Things, I have tried:

1. Wait 10 mins after run, nothing happend.
2. Changed priority on adb.exe to real time
3. Killed adb.exe (here, console started showing up Connection attempts: 1..2..3 ... nothing more)
4. Changed perspective to DDMS. Here, no devices are found. Hitted "reset adb" (here, console shows An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
5. In Window->Preferences->Android checked SDK location (no spaces)
6. Run emulator.exe -avd test2 from command line  (emulator-arm.exe stop working)
7. Installed different API. I had API 17 and I installed API 16 (all sub-things)
8. Run configuration Lauch as ... (not Launch Def. Activity)
9. Deleting avd's content in userdata fold and creating new
10. Run as admin
11. Check stackoverflow for all possible solutions
12. Minor restarting, creating new AVD, different  settings, ram size and stuff..

notes:
- I have new PC, there are no performance issues possible
- I am using Adt bundle windows x86_64 - 2013 02 19 build 21.1.0-569685
- UAC and all those stuff disabled
- Windows 7 64-bit
- Again, Never made it to lock screen, no log available

Comment: Restart your computer?
Try only starting one emulator (instead of multiple at once)?

Comment: sure. Tried run only 1 and waited 10 mins

Comment: first run takes long to load avd. if you see screen with android logo, please wait until it loads (it might be more than 10 mins)

Comment: Sounds like your configuration could be mucked up. You may want to uninstall everything from the ADT bundle, and re-install. Could you give a screenshot of your AVD manager?